# Sass/CSS: Stop fixed div from scrolling along with parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I've this two divs: parent div `#filterSelect` that englobates a set of filters, and its child div `#applyFilterIKnow` that is the "apply filters" button. `#applyFilterIKnow` is supposed to always be visible and fixed to the bottom of the `#filterSelect`div. The problem is that `#applyFilterIKnow` scrolls along with `#filterSelect`. Here's the CSS of both:

```
#filterSelect {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#applyFilterIKnow {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #4370d9;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I omitted some of the css relative to the background colors. Supposedly one of the solutions is to set `#filterSelect`'s position to relative, but that makes the whole div to overlap to the rest of the page's content. What can I do? Thanks in advance to anyone responding my doubt :(

Here are some screenshots related to the problem:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that your parent is also absolute. Absolute (or fixed) positioned elements behave differently when they are hosted within an absolute positioned parent element: They still follow their parent's constraints.

The only possible way (i know of) is to move your fixed element outside of its parent.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'll see if i can do that, because this is already build and maybe i'll have to chang a lot os js :s